# C# Resizing a panel from right to left

Tags: c#, resize, panel, picturebox, mousemove

I spent a few hours searching the internet for ways to take my panel and grab it from the left side and pull it left. I found many sources and I tried to alter it to my needs, but it always goes from left to right. My code I currently have is:

```
bool allowResize = false;

private void PanelResize_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        allowResize = false;            
    }

    private void PanelResize_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (allowResize)
        {
            FavoritesPanel.Width = PanelResize.Left + e.X;
        }
    }

    private void PanelResize_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        allowResize = true;
    }
```

"PanelResize" is a picturebox pushed to the left side of the panel. "FavoritesPanel" is the panel. Both are anchored to the top, bottom, and right side.

My overall question is, how can I correct my code to drag my panel from right to left?

Comment: Do you want to drag the "PanelResize" or resize the "FavoritesPanel". Your last question states, that you want to drag the panel, but in order for you to do that, you would need to set the 'Left' Property of the panel and not the width.

Comment: Essentially, I am using PanelResize as a gateway between the drag action and the FavoritesPanel object. So, when I drag PanelResize left FavoritesPanel follows in its footsteps. But, if I were to set the 'Left' property of the panel how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

problem is that default setting of changing Width of some panel means that it makes panel more width in way that right side is shifting to right direction.
You need two things. This what you have (resizing width) and second is that you need to shift whole panel to left side as long as you make it more width.

I have similar code here. I made code which allows you to roll up upper side of panel. So I had to do two things again: make my panel more height and shift whole panel more up. Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int actualCursorY;
    private int lastCursorY;
    private bool isDragged;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void barRadPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        lastCursorY = PointToClient(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)).Y;
        isDragged = true;
    }

    private void barRadPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragged = false;
    }

    private void barRadPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragged)
        {
            actualCursorY = PointToClient(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)).Y;
            mainRadPanel.Location = new Point(mainRadPanel.Location.X, actualCursorY);

            if (lastCursorY != actualCursorY)
            {
                mainRadPanel.Height -= actualCursorY - lastCursorY;
                lastCursorY = actualCursorY;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use

```
e.Y
```

instead of

```
PointToClient(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)).Y
```

but it made some errors.

This is what it does:

[image]